# Название мастей лошадей

Tags: этимология

Скажите, пожалуйста, откуда взялись странные слова, обозначающие некоторые масти лошадей? Ведь там, наряду с обычным серыми и рыжими, есть такие странные названия, как:
-игреневая
-соловая
-чалая
-каурая
-гнедая.
Что означают все эти слова (сами масти я знаю, меня интересует происхождение названий).
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё исключительно от полузабытых ныне старорусских названий цветов и оттенков.
Вы ещё не все привели.

~Игреневая: игрений - светло-рыжий, из тюркских.
~соловая: соловый - серый, древнерусское слово, отсюда "соловей".
~чалая: чалый - седой, серый, из тюркских. 
~гнедая - коричневый, общеславянкое, этимология неясна, возможно связано с гнида.
~каурая: каурый -  коричневый, древнерусское, связано, видимо с "курый" - мрачный.
~карий - черный, древнерусское, возможно развилось от того же "курый".   
~саврасый - серо-желтый, неясно, видимо окказиональное образование. 
~буланный - светло-желтый, из тюркских.
~сивый - темносерый, старославянское.

Сивка, бурка, вещая каурка - это серо-коричневый. Вот почему "вещая" - для меня загадка. Возможно, там должно было быть "вящая".

Comment: Светло - рыжий.